# How to stop blinking on recycler view with architecture components paging library

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I have a chat-like activity where I am using a RecyclerView with a PagedListAdaper to load a bunch of messages. I'm using a PositionalDataSource to load the data. The loading it's self works fine but when I send a message, I invalidate my datasource and the list gets remade. **My problem is that it blinks when it does that**:

[image: this is how it looks]

I have tried adding setHasStableIds(true) and overriding getItemId which would work on a simple adapter but it doesn't seem to work here. I also cannot seem to be able to just add an item to the getCurrentList() because it's not supported. Also, I'm not using a database, just making requests to a server.

So my questions are, is there a better way of doing this besides invalidating the data source? Is there a way to stop the list from blinking when sending a message? Or is this library just not suited for my chat activity?

**Edit**:

my diff callback

```
private val DIFF_CALLBACK: DiffCallback<MessageModel> = object : DiffCallback<MessageModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(@NonNull oldMessage: MessageModel, @NonNull newMessage: MessageModel) =
                oldMessage.id == newMessage.id


        override fun areContentsTheSame(@NonNull oldMessage: MessageModel, @NonNull newMessage: MessageModel) =
                oldMessage.equals(newMessage)
    }
```

**Edit2 I fixed it**:

So I managed to fix it by using PagedListAdapterHelper and setting it's list after the items loaded:

```
private var mHelper: PagedListAdapterHelper<MessageModel>? = null

init {
    mHelper = PagedListAdapterHelper(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)
    setHasStableIds(true)
}
fun setList(pagedList: PagedList<MessageModel>) {
    pagedList.addWeakCallback(pagedList.snapshot(), object:PagedList.Callback() {
        override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
            mHelper?.setList(pagedList)
        }

        override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {

        }

    })
}
```

Comment: what is `PagedListAdapterHelper`?

Comment: @sleepy have you got success? i am also looking for this

Comment: `PagedListAdapterHelper` deprecated in Paging Component

Comment: @sleepy I'm sleepy too

Comment: @sleepy have you got success? i am also looking for this

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi, hi~Do you find the way?

Answer (score 4):

PagedListAdapterHelper deprecated in Paging Component so we should use [AsyncPagedListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/AsyncPagedListDiffer) instead of it.

Code example:

```
    import android.arch.paging.AsyncPagedListDiffer;
    import android.arch.paging.PagedList;
    import android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    public class PagedItemsArrayAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Item, MyViewHolder> {

            private final AsyncPagedListDiffer<Item> mDiffer;

            public PagedItemsArrayAdapter() {
                super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
                mDiffer = new AsyncPagedListDiffer<>(this, DIFF_CALLBACK);
                setHasStableIds(true);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
               Item item = mDiffer.getItem(position);
               return item.id;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mDiffer.getItemCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void submitList(PagedList<Item> pagedList) {

                pagedList.addWeakCallback(pagedList.snapshot(), new PagedList.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
                        mDiffer.submitList(pagedList);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {

                    }
                });

            }


            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
                   Item item = mDiffer.getItem(position);
                   viewHolder.onBind(item); 
            }

            private static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Item oldItem, @NonNull Item newItem) {
                    return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Item oldItem, @NonNull Item newItem) {
                    return oldItem.equals(newItem);
                }
            };
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if orientation changes.

Comment: The callback is never getting called

Comment: hi, I found th callback is never called, because addWeakCallback after onInserted, have any other way?@seyfullah.bilgin

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: make sure to call the `callback` of `PositionalDataSource<T>.loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<T> callback)` synchronously in `loadInitial` without wrapping it in some kind of asynchronous success handler.

Explanation:

Blinking can be caused by asynchronous loads in your initial load i.e. in `PositionalDataSource<T>.loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<T> callback)`.

The following will happen when you do so:

Your data source gets invalidated which leads to the creation of a new `PagedList` (when created with `LivePagedListBuilder`). This newly created paged list will be passed to your adapter but it is still empty because you didn't call the callback directly in your initial load. This will lead to an empty list for as long as it takes for your callback to be called. This ultimately results in a flicker effect.

Comment: So you're saying that if I call the callback.onResult() on the main-thread, then the LivePagedListBuilder won't create a new empty PagedList instance, when the DataSource is invalidated?<br/>
<br/>
Because I've tried that and did a mHandler.post(callback.onResult()) ,where mHandler is from the MainLooper and it still created a new PagedList instance instead of using the old one. <br/>

I took a look through the invalidate() code and to me it just seemed that it will always create a new PagedList when invalidated, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I am calling it synchronously and it still blinks

Comment: Used rx in loadInitial etc. Changed to blocking. Still blinks.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the item animations.

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Comment: then animation is gone, but flickering stays. It shows for a second not initialized state.

Comment: For me it fixes the flickering, but it turns off all the other animations I wanted to keep (when an item is inserted, removed...)

Comment: also have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66222791/3496570

Comment: This solution doesn't stop the flickering after a datasource invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use sync in `loadInitial` and `loadAfter`, ie:

```
mLoadState.postValue(NetworkState.Loading);
try {
    mLoadState.postValue(NetworkState.DONE);
    ResultMessage<List<Achievement>> info = call.execute().body();
    if (info != null && info.isSuccess()) {
        List<Achievement> list = info.getData();
        callback.onResult(list, null, FIRST_PAGE + 1);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    mLoadState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR);
    mRetry.postValue(() -> loadInitial(params, callback));
    Log.d(TAG, "fail!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using `paging library 3` with `room`. We were getting flickering, blinking and scrolling effects after we wrote some next page data on database. Because we set the `PagingConfig`'s `initialLoadSize` different than `pageSize`. We have started to use same value for both of them and our problem has been fixed.